# get list of lists back from boolean slice in python

Tags: python

Consider the list of lists:
`contests = [[5, 1], [2, 1], [1, 1], [8, 1], [10, 0], [5, 0]]`

If I slice this list in order to recover the values that are equal to `1` in the second element of every list, I may do the following:

```
[sublist[1]==True for sublist in contests]
```

which gives:

```
[True, True, True, True, False, False]
```

Is there a way to get the list subset back from these list of boolean values, in order for the result to be:

`[[5, 1], [2, 1], [1, 1], [8, 1]`

I am aware of `itertools compress`, but that would force me to assign the result of `[sublist[1]==True for sublist in contests]` to an object and then subset like so:

```
from itertools import compress
contests = [[5, 1], [2, 1], [1, 1], [8, 1], [10, 0], [5, 0]]
bo = [True,True,True,True,False,False]

list(compress(contests, bo))
```

Is there maybe a one liner to achieve the same goal ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Were you looking for:

```
[sublist for sublist in contests if sublist[1]==True]
```

Note that `==True` is superfluous and you could just use:

```
[sublist for sublist in contests if sublist[1]]
```

Since this may confuse, please realise that `sublist[1]==True` ends up evaluating to `0==True` (which is `False`) or `1==True` (which is `True`). But of course, `sublist[1]==1` would have been clearer (and more specific). If you however choose to write `sublist[1]==True`, you may as well write `sublist[1]` since that evaluates to the exact same boolean values as per https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html

I.e. your solution:

```
contests = [[5, 1], [2, 1], [1, 1], [8, 1], [10, 0], [5, 0]]
result = [sublist for sublist in contests if sublist[1]]
print(result)
```

Comment: oh yes, sure. that way I am slicing the list right and not creating a boolean ? subtle difference.

Comment: *True* is not superfluous because the question states that the second element in the sublist must be equal to 1. If the value was non-zero your second example would match. And while we're being pedantic, testing for equality to *True* is not really appropriate because it misleads the reader even though *True* is expected to be arithmetically equal to 1

Comment: @BrutusForcus I think you're wrong on both counts; if you actually run the code, it works fine in both instances. I would have written `if sublist[1]==1`, but I chose not to, to stay close to OP's example. `1` is truthy in Python, it all works. You're also wrong about that not being appropriate - from the Python documentation "Any object can be tested for truth value, for use in an if or while condition or as operand of the Boolean operations below." https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html  Not exactly clear code, but if you're going to compare `1` to `True`, you mas as well skip it.

Answer (score 1):

You need this trivial list compression.

```
contests = [[5, 1], [2, 1], [1, 1], [8, 1], [10, 0], [5, 0]]
sub = [s for s in contests if s[1] == 1]
```